# How do I insert a new line for every two lines except when encountering two consecutive new lines?

Tags: regex, macos, perl, awk, sed

I am trying to insert a new line for every two lines of text, except I want to restart this pattern whenever a new paragraph (two consecutive new lines) is encountered. (My desired output should not have three consecutive new lines.)

For example, here is my input text:

```
This is my first
line to appear in
the text.

I need the second
line to appear in
the way that follows
the pattern specified.

I am not sure if
the third line will
appear as I want it
to appear because sometimes
the new line happens where
there are two consecutive 
new lines.
```

And here's is my desired output:

```
This is my first
line to appear in

the text.

I need the second
line to appear in

the way that follows
the pattern specified.

I am not sure if
the third line will

appear as I want it
to appear because sometimes

the new line happens where
there are two consecutive

new lines.
```

I have tried using awk:

```
    awk -v n=2 '1; NR % n == 0 {print ""}'
```

but this command does not restart the pattern after a new paragraph. Instead, I would get the following output from my example text above:

```
This is my first
line to appear in

the text.


I need the second

line to appear in
the way that follows

the pattern specified.


I am not sure if
the third line will

appear as I want it
to appear because sometimes

the new line happens where
there are two consecutive

new lines.
```

As this undesired output shows, without the restarting of the pattern, I would get instances of three consecutive new lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Paragraph mode in perl could help:

```
perl -00 -ple 's/.*\n.*\n/$&\n/g'
```

output

```
This is my first
line to appear in

the text.

I need the second
line to appear in

the way that follows
the pattern specified.

I am not sure if
the third line will

appear as I want it
to appear because sometimes

the new line happens where
there are two consecutive 

new lines.
```

Based on @Borodin comment:

```
perl -00 -ple 's/(?:.*\n){2}\K/\n/g'
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer provides both outcomes I desired: 1) repeats pattern and 2) does not produce three consecutive new lines.

Comment: The `/m` modifier is superfluous here, as you don't use either `$` or `^` in the pattern. It would perhaps be better written as `s/.*\n.*\n\K/\n/g` or `s/(?:.*\n){2}\K/\n/g`

Answer (score 3):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -00 -ple '$i = 0; s/\n/($i++ % 2) ? "\n\n" : "\n"/eg'
```

- `-00` turns on the "paragraph mode", i.e. Perl reads the input in blocks separated by at least two newlines.
- `-l` removes the two newlines from the end of each block after reading it, but returns them back before printing, avoiding three consecutive newlines.
- `/e` evaluates the right hand side of a substitution as code.
- `$i++ % 2` is the increment plus the modulo. It returns 1 for line 1, 3, 5 etc. in each block.
- `condition ? then : else` is the ternary operator. Newlines on lines 1, 3, 5... will be replaced by two newlines, the other ones will stay.
- `$i` is reset for each block to start from 0 again.

Comment: Thank you for this solution.

Comment: you probably mean `-ple` not only `-pe`.

Comment: @jm666: True, fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This will also restart the pattern for each paragraph:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = do { local $/; <DATA> };
my $i = 0;
$str =~ s/(\n+)/
  if (length $1 > 1) {
      $i = 0;
      "\n\n";
  }
  else {
      $i++ % 2 ? "\n\n" : "\n"
  }
  /ge;
print $str;

__DATA__
This is my first
line to appear in
the text.

I need the second
line to appear in
the way that follows
the pattern specified.

I am not sure if
the third line will
appear as I want it
to appear because sometimes
the new line happens where
there are two consecutive 
new lines.
```

**Output**:

```
This is my first
line to appear in

the text.

I need the second
line to appear in

the way that follows
the pattern specified.

I am not sure if
the third line will

appear as I want it
to appear because sometimes

the new line happens where
there are two consecutive 

new lines.
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/\S/!d;n;//!b;$!G' file
```

Delete all empty lines ahead of non-empty line, print it, if the next line is empty break out, otherwise append a newline (unless it is the last line) and repeat.

If you prefer an empty line to signify the last true couplet:

```
sed '/\S/!d;n;//G' file
```

As an afterthought, to group consecutive lines programmatically:

```
sed '/\S/!d;:a;N;/\n\s*$/b;s/[^\n]*/&/5;Ta;G' file
```

This will split texts into groups of no more than five lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you wait till you know if the next line is empty to make a decision about inserting a new-line, this becomes relatively straightforward.  Here expressed in awk:

*parse.awk*

```awk
# Remember line count in the paragraph with n
NF  { n++ }
!NF { n=0 }

# Only emit new-line if n is non-zero and the previous line 
# number is divisible by m
n>=m && (n-1)%m==0 { printf "\n" }

# Print $0
1
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -v m=2 -f parse.awk file
```

Or, for example, like this:

```
awk -f parse.awk m=2 file m=3 file
```

Below is the output of the second invocation with the following header added to the script (The header is GNU awk specific):

```
BEGINFILE { 
  n = 0; 
  if(FNR != NR) 
    printf "\n\n"; print "===>>>   " FILENAME ", m=" m "   <<<==="
}
```

Output:

```
===>>>   file, m=2   <<<===
This is my first
line to appear in

the text.

I need the second
line to appear in

the way that follows
the pattern specified.

I am not sure if
the third line will

appear as I want it
to appear because sometimes

the new line happens where
there are two consecutive 

new lines.


===>>>   file, m=3   <<<===
This is my first
line to appear in
the text.

I need the second
line to appear in
the way that follows

the pattern specified.

I am not sure if
the third line will
appear as I want it

to appear because sometimes
the new line happens where
there are two consecutive 

new lines.
```

Golfed version:

```
{n=NF?n+1:0}(n-1)%m==0&&n>=m{printf "\n"}1
```